# How can I embed a webform in an Ionic React app?

Tags: webforms

Webform has a Share submodule that can be used [in decoupled situations.](https://www.jrockowitz.com/blog/webform-sharing)

There is a [video tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMgOprfJTWA).

However, I'm having trouble getting my webform embedded in my Ionic React app.

What I have done

1. Went to `/admin/structure/webform/config` and selected *Enable form sharing* under **Form share settings**.
2. Went to `/admin/structure/webform`, clicked the more info triangle, selected **Share**.

I now have the option to choose from JavaScript, Resizing iframe, and Fixed iframe, but all of these use `document.write`, which won't work with Ionic because the document has already been written.

Comment: Yeh that document.write is an old-school hack and maybe it needs to be reworked.  Thanks for posting what looks like a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is specifically how to do this in Ionic + React.

First, Webform share uses the [iframe-resizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iframe-resizer) library, which has an official [react component.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iframe-resizer-react)

So install the library into your app:

`npm install iframe-resizer-react`

Then add a component such as **WebformContact.tsx** (this example uses TypeScript):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  IonContent, IonPage,
} from '@ionic/react';
import IframeResizer from 'iframe-resizer-react';

const styleWebformIframeEmbed: React.CSSProperties = {
  width: '1px',
  minWidth: '100%',
};

const WebformContact = () => (
  <IonPage>
    <IonContent>
      <IframeResizer
        src="https://example.com/webform/MY-WEBFORM-MACHINENAME/share/iframe-resizer/4.2.10"
        title="MY WEBFORM TITLE"
        frameBorder="0"
        allowFullScreen
        style={styleWebformIframeEmbed}
      />
    </IonContent>
  </IonPage>
);
export default WebformContact;
```

Note that you need to install the same version of `iframe-resizer` in both webform (drupal) + your ionic app.

Also note that if your site is `https`, you should be sure to specify that in the `src` tag; when React is hosted by Ionic, it will be run from http://localhost (Android) or http://capacitor (iOS), so if you do not specify `https` for the server, you will get a difficult to understand error:

> iframeResizer.js:822 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow':
> The target origin provided

But really what this means is that you are trying to access an https server in an iframe with http.  So specify https!